While using ObjectBox as a Vectorstore I got this error: "CoreException: 10001 (ILLEGAL_STATE) - Cannot open store" What should I do?
I was trying to make a simple Q/A app with RAG with ObjectBox as the vector store.
I have
This is the code I was using:
import streamlit as st
import os
from langchain_groq import ChatGroq
from langchain_community.document_loaders import PyPDFDirectoryLoader
from langchain_community.embeddings import OllamaEmbeddings
from langchain.text_splitter import RecursiveCharacterTextSplitter
from langchain.chains.combine_documents import create_stuff_documents_chain
from langchain_core.prompts import ChatPromptTemplate
from langchain.chains import create_retrieval_chain
from langchain_objectbox.vectorstores import ObjectBox
import time

groq_api_key = "The Groq API Key"

st.title("Objectbox VectorsstoreDB with Llama3")

llm = ChatGroq(groq_api_key=groq_api_key, model_name="Llama3-8b-8192")

prompt = ChatPromptTemplate.from_template(
    """
    Answer the questions based on the provided context only.
    Please provide te most accurate response based on the question
    <<context>>
    {context}
    <<context>>
    Questions: {input}
"""
)

if "vector" not in st.session_state:
        st.session_state.embeddings=OllamaEmbeddings()
        st.session_state.loader = PyPDFDirectoryLoader("./us_census") # Data Ingestion
        st.session_state.docs = st.session_state.loader.load() # Document loading
        st.session_state.text_splitter = RecursiveCharacterTextSplitter(chunk_size=1000,chunk_overlap=200) # Chunk Creation
        st.session_state.final_documents = st.session_state.text_splitter.split_documents(st.session_state.docs[:20]) # Splitting
        st.session_state.vectors = ObjectBox.from_documents(st.session_state.final_documents,st.session_state.embeddings,embedding_dimensions=768) # Vector Ollama embeddings
        print("hi")

input_prompt = st.text_input("Input Prompt")

if st.button("Documents Embedding"):
    #vector_embedding()
    st.write("Vector Store DB is Ready")

if input_prompt:
    document_chain = create_stuff_documents_chain(llm,prompt)
    retriever = st.session_state.vectors.as_retriever()
    retrieval_chain = create_retrieval_chain(retriever,document_chain)
    start = time.process_time()
    response = retrieval_chain.invoke({"input":input_prompt})
    print("Response time:",time.process_time()-start)
    st.write(response['answer'])

    # Streamlit expander
    with st.expander("Doc similarity search"):
        # finding relevant chunks
        for i, doc in enumerate(response["context"]):
            st.write(doc.page_content)
            st.write("-------------------------")

Error Message
After I entered an input through the streamlit input text box, This is the error I got:
CoreException: 10001 (ILLEGAL_STATE) - Cannot open store: another store is still open using the same path: "C:\Users\RISHAV BHATTACHARJEE\Desktop\RB Workbase\Generative-AI\Langchain\ObjectBox\objectbox"
Traceback:
File "C:\Users\RISHAV BHATTACHARJEE\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\streamlit\runtime\scriptrunner\script_runner.py", line 584, in _run_script
exec(code, module.dict)
File "C:\Users\RISHAV BHATTACHARJEE\Desktop\RB Workbase\Generative-AI\Langchain\ObjectBox\app.py", line 38, in 
st.session_state.vectors = ObjectBox.from_documents(st.session_state.final_documents,st.session_state.embeddings,embedding_dimensions=768) # Vector Ollama embeddings
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\RISHAV BHATTACHARJEE\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\langchain_core\vectorstores.py", line 550, in from_documents
return cls.from_texts(texts, embedding, metadatas=metadatas, **kwargs)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\RISHAV BHATTACHARJEE\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\langchain_objectbox\vectorstores.py", line 215, in from_texts
ob = cls(embedding, **kwargs)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\RISHAV BHATTACHARJEE\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\langchain_objectbox\vectorstores.py", line 52, in init
self._db = self._create_objectbox_db()
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\RISHAV BHATTACHARJEE\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\langchain_objectbox\vectorstores.py", line 252, in _create_objectbox_db
return objectbox.Store(model=model,directory=db_path)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\RISHAV BHATTACHARJEE\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\objectbox\store.py", line 168, in init
self._c_store = c.obx_store_open(options._c_handle)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\RISHAV BHATTACHARJEE\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\objectbox\c.py", line 295, in check_result
raise CoreException(C.obx_last_error_code())

The error raises from running multiple instances of ObjectBox for the same database store and is related to the way your streamlit app script was set setup.
It can be fixed with two modifications to your script:

Put your "session_state" code block into a function e.g. vector_embeddings, rename "vector" to "vectors" typo which then correctly checks if ObjectBox is already set up:

def vector_embedding():
    if "vectors" not in st.session_state:
            st.session_state.embeddings=OllamaEmbeddings()
            st.session_state.loader = PyPDFDirectoryLoader("./us_census") # Data Ingestion
            st.session_state.docs = st.session_state.loader.load() # Document loading
            st.session_state.text_splitter = RecursiveCharacterTextSplitter(chunk_size=1000,chunk_overlap=200) # Chunk Creation
            st.session_state.final_documents = st.session_state.text_splitter.split_documents(st.session_state.docs[:20]) # Splitting
            st.session_state.vectors = ObjectBox.from_documents(st.session_state.final_documents,st.session_state.embeddings,embedding_dimensions=768) # Vector Ollama embeddings
            print("hi")


Uncomment the function call

if st.button("Documents Embedding"):
    vector_embedding()
    st.write("Vector Store DB is Ready")

This should fix the problem and then hopefully work as desired in the originating video tutorial.

Just delete the objectbox folder from the local directory..and restart your project. It will resolve this error.
